# Download Files To Internal Storage

Tags: android, file, runtime, internal-storage

I am having some trouble with my application.

I wanted to download the files and then save them into my apps drawable folder, but since that is not an option because app is read only, I want to save the downloaded file into internal storage so that only my app can access them.
If I cannot directly download the file to internal storage, can I read from downloads folder and then save it to internal storage?

Either way, I have the download method, I just need to know where to save the downloaded file and how to access it at runtime and persistently store it in internal storage.

Comment: Add your code please and the part that you are looking for !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try having a look at

```
_context.getFilesDir();
```

and

```
_context.getExternalFilesDir();
```

Answer (score -1):

/**
 * Copies a private raw resource content to a publicly readable
 * file such that the latter can be shared with other applications.
 */

> ```
> private void copyPrivateRawResourceToPubliclyAccessibleFile() {
>     InputStream inputStream = null;
>     FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
>     try {
>         inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.robot);
>         outputStream = openFileOutput(SHARED_FILE_NAME,
>                 Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
>         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
>         int length = 0;
>         try {
>             while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
>                 outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
>             }
>         } catch (IOException ioe) {
>             /* ignore */
>         }
>     } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
>         /* ignore */
>     } finally {
>         try {
>             inputStream.close();
>         } catch (IOException ioe) {
>            /* ignore */
>         }
>         try {
>             outputStream.close();
>         } catch (IOException ioe) {
>            /* ignore */
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: You don't understand, i want only my app to have access to the files, not the user and not other apps.

Comment: @Pavle37 can you check my answer !

Comment: What is R.raw.robot? Is that a file you've created in the raw folder in which you store data? And my downloaded file is located in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD, i think the outputStream won't read it if i just type in the name... Also my files are images and sounds.

Comment: This bears absolutely no relationship to the question asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton flaged to delete